# Is size value used for a Gen's sample taking a custom generator?

Tags: f#, fscheck

I'm generating custom data using `FsCheck`'s `Gen`.

Suppose you have a function returning `Gen<'T>`:

```
let chooseRectangle widthMax heightMax offset =
   gen {
       let! left = Gen.choose(0, widthMax-offset)
       let! top = Gen.choose(0, heightMax-offset)
       let! width = Gen.choose(offset, widthMax-left)
       let! height = Gen.choose(offset, heightMax-top)
       return { Left=left
                Top=top
                Width=width
                Height=height
               }
   }
```

which is then used for generating data:

```
Gen.sample 0 10 (chooseRectangle 400 200 10)
```

is the `size` argument (first one) used in this case and does it influence the value repartition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not in your case, as far as I can tell.

That first argument is size. `sample` threads it through into the generator you call it with, but what that generator does with it is up to that particular implementation. For sequence generators it may for instance control the length of the sequence.

Your generator however is solely built on top of `Gen.choose`, which explicitly ignores it:

```
let choose (l, h) = Gen (fun _ r -> range (l,h) r |> fst)
```

where size is the `_` argument. See [here](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/master/src/FsCheck/Gen.fs#L163).

Comment: thanks, I edited my question since I meant size as the name of the parameter.